# visualforce pagination does not work

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I mentioned the code below, when i click on next, first, previous or last, it does not work

visualforce code

```
<apex:page
sidebar="false"
Controller="Invoice_details"
showHeader="False"
docType="html-5.0"
readOnly="true"
>
<html
    xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
>
    <head>
    <body>
        <apex:slds />
        <style>
        .ui-corner-all{ z-index: 1; top: 34px; left: 200px; display: block;
        width: 403px; background-color: lightgray; } .displayNone {
        display:none; } .displayBlock { display:block; }
        .ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url(/img/loading32.gif)
        right center no-repeat; background-size:15px 15px; } .placeHolder {
        font-style: italic; margin-left : 50px; margin-top : 20px; Width :
        50rem; } .Showall { font-style: bold; margin-left : 160px; margin-top
        : 120px; width : 50rem; } .space { font-style: italic; font-size :
        25px; margin-left : 50px; margin-top : 20px; }
        .slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none{ font-size : 2 rem; }
        .nishant{ font.size : 1 rem; } .formelement{ <div
        class="slds-form-element"> <label class="slds-form-element__label"
        for="checkbox-id-01">Form Element Label</label> <div
        class="slds-form-element__control"> <span class="slds-checkbox
        slds-checkbox_standalone"> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-id-01"
        name="label" value="option" disabled="" checked="" /> <span
        class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span> </span> </div> </div> }
        .Outputpanel{ margin-bottom : 50px; margin-top : 20px; margin-left
        :20px; }
        </style>
        <apex:form styleClass="Showall">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
            <span
                class="slds-form-element__label slds-m-bottom_none"
                style="font-size:.90rem"
            >
                Show All
            </span>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="checkbox-toggle-15"
                value="checkbox-toggle-15"
                aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-15"
                checked=""
            />
            <span
                id="checkbox-toggle-15"
                class="slds-checkbox_faux_container"
                aria-live="assertive"
                style="margin-left:15px"
            >
                <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_on">Enabled</span>
                <span class="slds-checkbox_off">Disabled</span>
            </span>
            </label>
        </div>
        </apex:form>
        <apex:form id="frm" styleClass="placeHolder">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-space">
            <div class="slds-col">
            <span
                >Date From
                <apex:inputfield
                value="{!InvoiceInfo.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c}"
                id="datefrom"
                />
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-col">
            <span
                >Date To
                <apex:inputfield
                value="{!InvoiceInfo.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c}"
                id="dateto"
                onSelect="display()"
                />
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </apex:form>
        <apex:form styleClass="Outputpanel" id="Pageid">
        <apex:pageBlock id="display1">
            <apex:pageMessages showDetail="true"></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false">
            <apex:pageBlockTable
                value="{!InvoiceList}"
                var="rs"
                columnsWidth="45px"
            >
                <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!rs.attachments}">
                <selectoptions value="{!rs.attachments}" />
                </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                <apex:column style="formelement" />
                <apex:column
                value="{!rs.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c }"
                headerValue="DATE"
                />
                <apex:column
                value="{!rs.kognoz1__Account__c}"
                headerValue="Account"
                />
                <apex:column
                value="{!rs.kognoz1__Opportunity__c}"
                headerValue="Opportunity"
                />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
            <apex:commandLink
                action="{!Beginning}"
                reRender="Pageid"
                status="status"
                >FIRST</apex:commandLink
            >
            <apex:commandLink
                action="{!Next}"
                reRender="getDisablePrevious"
                rendered="true"
                status="status"
                >NEXT</apex:commandLink
            >
            <apex:commandLink
                action="{!Previous}"
                reRender="getDisableNext"
                status="status"
                >PREVIOUS</apex:commandLink
            >
            <apex:commandLink
                action="{!End}"
                reRender="getTotalPages"
                status="status"
                >LAST</apex:commandLink
            >
            <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Loading" />
            </apex:panelGrid>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
    </head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeValue(radioButton) { var chk =
    document.getElementsByClassName('selection'); for (var i=0; i<chk.length;
    i++) { if(radioButton.value == chk[i].value) { chk[i].checked = true; }
    else { chk[i].checked = false; } } }
    </script>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

apex controller

```
Public without sharing class  Invoice_details {

    public List<kognoz1__Invoice2__c> InvoiceList {get;set;}
    public kognoz1__Invoice2__c InvoiceInfo { get;set;}
    public static String StartDate {get;set;}
    public List<kognoz1__Invoice2__c> getInvoicedetails { get;set;}
    public static String EndDate {get;set;}
    public static string querystr;
    private integer counter = 0; 
    private integer list_size=20;
    private integer total_size = 20;

    public Invoice_details(){ 
        InvoiceInfo = new kognoz1__Invoice2__c ();
        InvoiceList = [SELECT Id,kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c, kognoz1__Account__c, kognoz1__Opportunity__c FROM kognoz1__Invoice2__c order by kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c limit : list_size offset : counter ];
        total_size = [select count() from kognoz1__Invoice2__c];
        //InvoiceList = Database.query(querystr);
        //List<kognoz1__Invoice2__c> KI = [SELECT Id,kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c, kognoz1__Account__c, kognoz1__Opportunity__c FROM kognoz1__Invoice2__c ]; 
    }
    /* public PageReference runSearch(){
        InvoiceList.clear();
        if(InvoiceInfo.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c != null & InvoiceInfo.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c != null ){
        startDate=String.valueOf(InvoiceInfo.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c).left(10);
        endDate=String.valueOf(InvoiceInfo.kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c).left(10);
        String querystr='SELECT Id,kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c, kognoz1__Account__c, kognoz1__Opportunity__c FROM kognoz1__Invoice2__c WHERE kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c ='+startDate+' AND kognoz1__Invoice_Date__c='+ endDate;
        InvoiceList = Database.query(querystr);
        }
        return null;
    } */ 
    public Pagereference Beginning() { 
        counter = 0;
        return null;
    }

    public Pagereference Previous() { 
        counter = counter-list_size;
        return null;
    }

    public Pagereference Next() { 
        counter = counter+list_size;
        return null;
    }


    public Pagereference End() { 
        counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
        if(counter==total_size){
            counter=counter-list_size;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Boolean getDisablePrevious() { 
        if (counter>0) {
        return false;
        } else return true;
    }

    public Boolean getDisableNext() {
        if (counter + list_size < total_size){ 

            return false;} else return true;
        }

    public Integer getTotal_size() {
        return total_size;
    }

    public Integer getPageNumber() {
        return counter/list_size + 1;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
            if(total_size==null)
                total_size=0;

            if (math.mod(total_size, list_size) > 0) {
            return total_size/list_size + 1;
            } else {
            return (total_size/list_size);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first immediate problem I see is that you have multiple `apex:form` elements. This can cause a loss of data/view state, as well as other performance problems. Consolidate all of your code under a single `apex:form`.

As an aside, There's no need to return a PageReference if you will only ever return a null value, e.g.:

```
public void Next() { 
    counter += list_size;
}
```

Also, there's no need for most of the if-else statements you have, e.g.:

```
public Boolean getDisableNext() {
    return counter + list_size >= total_size;
}
```

Comment: sorry but did not help